FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) Tunnel aaa.com not found
I use ngrok and
I got the error "FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) Tunnel aaa.com not found" in Flutter project.
My code is
class HttpApi {

  static const _domain = 'xxx.com';

  static const _timeout = 60;

  static final client = HttpClient();
  static final _http = IOClient(client);

  static Future<Response> apiGet(
    String path, [
    bool needToken = false,
    bool isApiInfo = false,
  ]) async {
    final urlBase = isApiInfo ? _domain : Global().apiDomain;
    final url = Uri.parse(urlBase + path);
    final headers = await _createTokenHeaderks(needToken);
    final res = await _http.get(url, headers: headers).timeout(
      const Duration(seconds: _timeout),
      onTimeout: () {
        throw TimeoutException('Timeout error in apiGet.');
      },
    );
    _log(res, null);
    return _handleResponse(res);
  }

  static Future<Response> apiPost(
    String urls,
    Map<String, dynamic>? body, [
    bool needToken = false,
  ]) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(Global().apiDomain + urls);
    final jsonBody = body != null ? jsonEncode(body) : null;
    final headers = await _createTokenHeaders(needToken);
    final res = await _http.post(url, headers: headers, body: jsonBody).timeout(
          const Duration(seconds: _timeout),
          onTimeout: () => throw TimeoutException('Timeout error in apiPost.'),
        );
    _log(res, body);
    return _handleResponse(res);
  }


I got the error
log] 404 POST aaa.com/auth/login
[log] FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
Tunnel aaa.com not found
It looks URL is wrong but
I set
static const _domain = 'xxx.com';
so I don’t know why I got this error.
Cash or something?
Any possiblity mistake in code?
I tried to delete emulator and remake it again but nothing change.

Check these points hope these helps...

Make sure that API.loginURL is correctly set to the endpoint of the login API you're trying to access. Ensure that the URL is properly formatted and accessible.
Inspect response with : print(await streamedResponse.stream.bytesToString());
Ensure that device is connected to the internet.
Put your code in try and catch blocks to handle error response


did u forgot to add https:// to your domain?
